# Software keyboard on iphone X simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode9, iphone-x

How can I simulate the keyboard on an iPhone X simulator?
For some reason the option "Toggle software keyboard" is disabled in the menu, which is not happening in any other device simulator.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Can you file a bug at https://bugreport.apple.com? Please include the output of `xcrun simctl diagnose` with that simulator booted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to disable *Send Menu Keyboard Shortcuts To Device*. Then, hit `shift`+`command`+`k` to show the keyboard. It's the same with the iPad Simulators.

Answer (score 0):

From the menu bar, click *Hardware* then *Keyboard*.

Make sure *Send Menu Keyboard Shortcuts* is unchecked, then make sure *Connect Hardware Keyboard* is checked. This should solve the issue